# C++: Iteratively call a member's object methods /// a table of objects

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of object classes (`A`, `B` and `C` in this example) which I instantiate in my application. They all inherit one and a same interface, which I call `Base`. I want to interate over the objects and do a call on them.

Here are the classes and the base:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual CResult init() noexcept;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    ...
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    ...
};

class C : public Base
{
public:
    ...
};
```

I have then an instance of `A`, `B` and `C` in the application, together with its `init()` method:

```
class Application
{
public:
    CResult init() noexcept;
private:
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};

CResult Application::init()
{
    /// iterate on a, b, c and call .init()
    /// add code
}
```

Now, I want to call the `init()` methods of all my objects `a`, `b` and `c` iteratively.
That would mean I need to define a table with `a`, `b` and `c` "references" (I say references, but yes it is not possible to have, say, vector of object references). Then to iterate over the table and call each member's `init()` method.

What is the best OOP way to achieve this? Can anyone share sample code with the table and the iteration?

Comment: If there are only a few, then don't iterate:  `a.init(); b.init(); c.init();`  IMHO, it's not worth the time or effort to figure out how to iterate over a small quantity of members.  You'll save more development time by listing them individually.

Comment: Not answering your question, but if you simply used the constructors instead of a delayed `init` calls, this would be done correctly automatically.

Comment: if you just are calling one method on them then I bet that the code to generate , maintain and iterate will be longer than simply invoking them explicitly, plus future maintainers will curse you

Comment: I want to improve the maintenance :) The code currently is invoking the ```init()'s``` one by one, but is also invoking other methods in the same manner like the ```init```.
That does not look good at all, mostly in term of maintenance.
Additionally, each call's return value needs to be analyzed (basically checked for OK or NOK).
A table with iteration will greatly improve the architecture.
The example contains 3 objects, but in my case I have 20+.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably this:

```
Base *ptrs[] = {&a, &b, &c};
for (auto ptr : ptrs)
    ptr->init();
```

If the variables had the same type, you could shorten this to `for (auto ptr : {&a, &b, &c})`. But since the types are different, you have to manually spell the pointer type when creating the array.

Comment: Looking for best solution in terms of Object Oriented Programming.
The iteration is necessary, as the objects are not a few. I just want to make the program more flexible and get rid of the individual calls.
Also, I want to analyze the return result but not flood the code with ```if```s

Comment: @SebastianGreen *"I want to analyze the return resul"* Go ahead? Since I don't know what you want to do with the result, I can't tell you how to do it. *"I just want to ... get rid of the individual calls"* Mhm, I've shown you how to do. *"Looking for best solution in terms of Object Oriented Programming"* Do you mean this approach is somehow "not OOP enough"?

Comment: @HoluBlackCat Thanks for the code snippet, that is doing the job fine.
But yes, it looks to me not OOP enough, you have it spotted right.
Can you think of good solution without explicit pointers usage?

Comment: @SebastianGreen A loop is just a loop, you can't make it "more OOP" or "less OOP", and using raw pointers doesn't make it "less OOP", or "less cool". Don't get too fixated on OOP, it's just a tool (and so are raw pointers), and more OOP doesn't always make your code better.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it using a std::vector. The following private member in the `Application` class definition holds the list of components:

```
std::vector<Base *> m_components;
```

The initialization of the list is currently in the constructor:

```
Application::Application()
{
    m_components.push_back(&a);
    m_components.push_back(&b);
    m_components.push_back(&c);
    /// add additional components as needed
}

CResult Application::init()
{
    // call all components' init
    for(const auto& cmp: m_components) 
    {
        CResult rc = cmp->init();
        if(rc != CResult::OK)
        {
            // error; report, break the initalization
        }
    }
    // initialization passed
}
```

The same approach can be used for deinit, start, stop, etc methods, and make the code quite readable and maintainable.